# Cordova: Azure Devops Pipeline Xcode build failed: Pods-Name does not support provisioning profiles. Pods-Name does not support provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-pipelines

Error:

> Pods-Name does not support provisioning profiles. Pods-Name does not
> support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile
> MobileAppProvisioning has been manually specified. Set the
> provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings
> editor. (in target 'Pods-Name' from project 'Pods')

- Xcode: 12.4
- Cordova CLI: 10.0.0
- cordova-ios: 6.2.0

I build the ios app using the Ionic Cordova framework and build and deploy using Azure pipelines(CI).
so, I have the following tasks in my Azure pipeline:

- npm install
- install cocoapod
- cordova platform add ios
- cordova build ios
- installing apple certificates
- **Xcode build - throws the error when ARCHIVE with Above mentioned error**
- Copy file to artifacts
- Publish artefacts

I have searched online for this and the solution is to change the Podfile and add the below code:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

But, As Azure pipeline generates the ios project dynamically when I run the command Cordova platform add ios and Pod file generates dynamically.

so, How to modify the Podfile in Azure pipeline to update the Podfile and resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova does not add support for iOS orientation by default, but you can get there by adding build hooks.

To make this working, I followed these steps:

Add the following to your config.xml file:

```
<platform name="ios">
        <hook src="iosAfterPlatformAdd.js" type="after_platform_add" />
</platform>
```

Create a file named iosAfterPlatformAdd.js in the top-level directory and copy the below code in the file:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
console.log('iosAfterPlatformAdd hook called');

execSync(`cd platforms/ios && pod deintegrate && cd ../../`, {
  stdio: "inherit"
});

const searchString = 'use_frameworks!';
const fileName = './platforms/ios/Podfile';
const appendText = `${searchString}
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
    end
  end
end`;

try {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
  let content = data.replace(searchString, appendText);
  const updatedData = fs.writeFileSync(fileName, content);
  console.log('Podfile', content);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}

execSync("pod install --project-directory='./platforms/ios/'", {
  stdio: "inherit"
});
execSync("pod update --project-directory='./platforms/ios/'", {
  stdio: "inherit"
});
```

From the command line, run the below commands to change the Podfile automatically:

```
cordova platform rm ios

cordova platform add ios
```

You should see the added lines in the Podfile file at this point.
then the Archive and resolved the issue.